# React Native FlatList not keeping state on modal

Tags: javascript, react-native

For context, i'm making a dynamic form, in which the user creates he's questions and the type of each question, like a simple text input, or even a image input. The list of questions is gathered from a local SQLite Database, and used for the data of the FlatList. To answer an image question, I use a modal from the react-native-modal module. The thing is, when the modal is show, I lose the state of all the other fields, losing all the previous answers. 

Here is my code of the item:
By the way, don't mind the tags to much, i'm using styled-components for most of the styling, and some variable names are in portuguese, so keep that in mind.
The camera is the react-native-camera module.

```
 function Item({ info, index }) {
    const [resp, setResp] = useState(
      DATA[index].resposta ? DATA[index].resposta : '',
    );
    // controla as respostas de cada pergunta
    useEffect(() => {
      dados[index] = {
        nome_pergunta: info.nome ? info.nome : info.nome_pergunta,
        resposta: resp,
        id_pergunta: info.id_pergunta,
        id_resposta: info.id_resposta ? info.id_resposta : null,
      };
    }, [resp]);
    // caso o input seja do tipo texto
    if (info.tipo === 'text') {
      return (
        <BlocoText>
          <Label>{info.nome}</Label>
          <Input
            //placeholder={info.nome}
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            value={resp}
            onChangeText={value => {
              setResp(value);
            }}
          />
        </BlocoText>
      );
    }
    // caso o input seja do tipo numero
    else if (info.tipo === 'number') {
      return (
        <BlocoText>
          <Label>{info.nome}</Label>
          <Input
            //placeholder={info.nome}
            //placeholderTextColor="white"
            value={resp}
            onChangeText={value => {
              setResp(value);
            }}
            keyboardType="decimal-pad"
          />
        </BlocoText>
      );
    }
    // caso o input seja do tipo multipla escolha
    else if (info.tipo === 'select') {
      const op = info.opcoes.split(',');
      let items = [];
      op.forEach(element => {
        items.push({
          color: '#000',
          key: element.trim(),
          value: element.trim(),
          label: element.trim(),
        });
      });
      return (
        <BlocoText>
          <Label>{info.nome}</Label>
          <BlocoText4>
            <Caixa>
              <RNPickerSelect
                value={resp}
                onValueChange={value => setResp(value)}
                placeholderTextColor="#000"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={true}
                items={items}
              />
            </Caixa>
          </BlocoText4>
        </BlocoText>
      );
    }
    // caso o input seja do tipo file
    else if (info.tipo === 'file') {
      return (
        <BlocoImagem>
          <BotaoImagem
            onPress={() => {
              setOption(index);
              setModalVisible(true);
            }}>
            <Tela2>
              <Label2>{info.nome}</Label2>
            </Tela2>

            <Tela2>
              <Icon
                name="camera"
                size={25}
                color="#FFF"
                styles={{ marginLeft: 50 }}
              />
            </Tela2>
          </BotaoImagem>
          <EnvolveImagem>
            <ImagemCampoNovo
              source={{
                uri: resp
                  ? 'data:image/png;base64,' + resp
                  : 'data:image/png;base64,' + Foto,
              }}
            />
          </EnvolveImagem>
        </BlocoImagem>
      );
    }
    // caso o input seja do tipo data
    else if (info.tipo === 'date') {
      return (
        <BlocoText>
          <Label>{info.nome}</Label>
          <DatePicker
            style={{ width: 295, marginLeft: 9 }}
            date={resp}
            mode="date"
            placeholder="Selecione Uma Data"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
            customStyles={{
              dateIcon: {
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                top: 4,
                marginLeft: 0,
              },
              dateInput: {
                marginLeft: 36,
              },
              // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
            }}
            onDateChange={date => {
              setResp(date);
            }}
          />
          <Ajusta2 />
        </BlocoText>
      );
    }
  }
```

And here is the code of my camera modal:

```
      <Modal
        transparent={false}
        isVisible={modalVisible}
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        onBackButtonPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(false);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#015',
            alignContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <RNCamera
            ref={ref => setCamera(ref)}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permissão para usar a câmera',
              message: 'Precisamos da sua permissão para usar a câmera.',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
            }}
            captureAudio={false}>
            <View style={{ flex: 5 }} />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} style={styles.capture}>
                <Icon name="camera" size={25} color="#7030a0" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </RNCamera>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

Finaly, the code of the FlatList:

```
          <Lista
            windowSize={6}
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Item info={item} index={DATA.indexOf(item)} />
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => '' + DATA.indexOf(item)}
          />
```

I tried using other rendering methods, like using a simple array.map function to render the items, which didn't work, as well as tried to find a alternative to the flatlist, since I have form in another page of the app, but a static one, and the modal works, not losing the state, but haven't maneged to find a good solution.

I have a theory that it might have something to do with the way i treat the change of the inputs. Maybe because of the useEffect being inside the Item itself, but i can't quite think of a better solution to the dynamic data storage, for latter saving purposes.

I'm open for sugestions, even if it means not using the FlatList itself.

*EDIT: Here is somewhat a snack to the problem= https://snack.expo.io/@suxgatov/7e28c3

I'm using react native cli in the project, so some things had to be removed in order for it to work. For example, the camera library was not working, but any modal has the same outcome, so it doesen't change the issue.

Comment: it's a bit hard to keep track. if you could provide a snack it would be helpful. first things that are coming to my mind are either lifting the state up or maybe using the extraData prop of FlatList

Comment: @TomSlutsky Thanks for the insight! Made a snack really close to the real project: https://snack.expo.io/@suxgatov/7e28c3.
I'm going to test your sugestion of the extraData prop form the flatlist and see if i have any luck with it.

Comment: just watched you snack. it looks pretty messy. consider separating the components to independent components that only communicate through props and callbacks. it is a bad habit to use global state as you do here.

Comment: Ok @TomSlutsky, i'm going to try that and cleanup the code a bit, i will update the snack as soon as i can.

Comment: sure. let me know if you need more direction

Comment: @TomSlutsky Thanks for the help with this issue Tom, I still have some new logic to think about because of the changes I made so far, but the modal itself works and i'm not loosing the state of all the other inputs anymore. As soon as I finish The changes I will set up a answer with the new version of the working code. Thank you very much again! :D